# store API response data on cache on server php

Tags: laravel, caching, server

I am using an API. The resquest-response time on the API takes too long time. So, due to this problem, I want to store the response on the Server but not on the browser. This is because, I want to display the result from cache for similar searches. I know, there are limitations on the accuracy on cached data, but that's another part which I don't want to include here.

I am using laravel framework and using this code for current moment as in the laravel documentation.

```
$expiresAt = Carbon::now()->addMinutes(10);

Cache::put('key', 'value', $expiresAt);
```

The problem with this code is, it stores cache on the browser only. But I want to store it on Server. I have heard about the [Memcached](http://www.memcached.org/) but could not implement it. I have also heard of `apc_store()` but I think it stores on local.  So, How can I store cache on server?

Comment: The cache is stored on your servers file system and with that method the cache should mean that is accessible to all users. But if your saying its not there must be something else going on. What are you storing from the API response the actual payload or just the data?

Comment: you mean to say, cache::put('') stores data on server ?

Comment: Yes by default the cache will be in `storage/framework/cache`.

Comment: What I want to do is when the user searches similar date in api, I want to display data from cache previously loaded by some other user. Is there a way to do that ?

Answer (score -1):

Similar to `Cache::put()`, you can use `Cache::pull()` to check for data saved (on the server).

```php
// Check cache for data
$cachedData = Cache::pull($key);

// Get new data if no cache
if (! $cachedData) {

    $newData = 'New Data';
    $expiresAt = Carbon::now()->addMinutes(10);

    // Save new data to cache
    $cachedData = Cache::put($key, $newData, $expiresAt);
}

echo $cachedData;
```

Comment: You actually want to use `Cache::has($key)` to check for existence of a particular key in the cache. If you do `Cache::pull($key)` it will remove it from the cache. In practice, the code above will cache 50% of requests as each time there is a cache-hit, it will remove that data from the cache causing the next request to be a cache-miss which will subsequently repopulate the cache.